# Docker & compose errors on Golang + React + MySQL app. Binary not found and unitilialized database

Tags: docker

I have a Golang + MySQL + React project. When I call to compose up I get some errors that I have to overcome: these are "binary not found" and "unitilialized database". I would be very grateful if someone could help me.

My directory tree is:

[image: screenshot]

The nd-back `Dockerfile` is:

```sh
FROM golang:1.22-alpine3.19
RUN addgroup chevi && adduser -S -G chevi chevi
USER chevi
WORKDIR /app/nd-back/
COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download
COPY --chown=chevi . .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o nd
CMD chown=chevi nd
EXPOSE 8000
CMD nd
```

The nd-front `Dockerfile` is:

```sh
FROM node:21-alpine3.18
RUN addgroup chevi && adduser -S -G chevi chevi
USER chevi
WORKDIR /app/nd-front/
COPY --chown=chevi package*.json .
RUN npm install
COPY --chown=chevi . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

And the `docker-compose.yml` file is:

```yaml
services:
  front:
    build: ./nd-front
    ports:
      - 80:3000
    volumes:
      - ./nd-front:/app/nd-front
  back:
    build: ./nd-back
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    environment:
      BBDD_URL: mysql://db/vdb
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: yes
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: xxxxxxxxxx
      MYSQL_DATABASE: xxxxxxxxxx
    volumes:
      - ./nd-back:/app/nd-back
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: mysql:8.3.0
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - vdb:/data/db
volumes:
  vdb:
```

When I make `docker compose up` I get there errors:

```
Attaching to back-1, db-1, front-1
db-1     | 2024-03-01 08:21:18+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.3.0-1.el8 started.
db-1     | 2024-03-01 08:21:18+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
db-1     | 2024-03-01 08:21:18+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.3.0-1.el8 started.
back-1   | /bin/sh: nd: not found
front-1  | 
front-1  | > nd-front@0.1.0 start
front-1  | > react-scripts start --host
front-1  | 
db-1     | 2024-03-01 08:21:18+00:00 [ERROR] [Entrypoint]: Database is uninitialized and password option is not specified
db-1     |     You need to specify one of the following as an environment variable:
db-1     |     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
db-1     |     - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD
db-1     |     - MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD
back-1 exited with code 127
db-1 exited with code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete all of the `volumes:` blocks in the Compose file.  The only place you should have a volume mounted is on the database container, and there the path needs to match the specific path required by its image (for MySQL, the container mount point must be `/var/lib/mysql`).

What's happening here is that the bind mount always completely hides the contents of the image at the mount point.  In both containers, you're doing all of the build work in a single directory in the Dockerfile, which is fine, but then you hide all of that work with the bind mount.  For the Go program, the compiled `nd` binary isn't there, which is why you get that "not found" error.

You also have a set of MySQL-related environment variables set on the `back` container, but at least some of them need to be set on the `db` container instead.  This is resulting in the set of errors resulting from missing MySQL environment variables.

The corrected Compose file should look more like

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  front:
    build: ./nd-front
    ports:
      - 80:3000
    # but no volumes:
  back:
    build: ./nd-back
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    environment:
      BBDD_URL: mysql://db/vdb
      MYSQL_USER: root            # assuming these values get used by
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: xxxxxxxxxx  # the application to authenticate to
      MYSQL_DATABASE: xxxxxxxxxx  # the database
    # no volumes:
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: mysql:8.3.0
    environment:                  # add this block in
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: yes
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: xxxxxxxxxx
      MYSQL_DATABASE: xxxxxxxxxx
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - vdb:/var/lib/mysql        # correct the path
volumes:
  vdb:
```